# What software was used to create this stylized screencast for Disqus 2012?

Tags: software, software-recommendation

I am making a video and want to have a stylized screencast like the Disqus 2012 video: https://vimeo.com/43917945

What software is used to create these sorts of animations?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to grab the screencast itself, a number of applications have been [discussed here before](https://video.stackexchange.com/q/4096/674).

Then use whatever video suite you feel most comfortable with - the angled view used in that clip can be done in Premier or various others, but it isn't very complex.

Comment: To follow up, I used Camtasia, FCPX and the FCPeffect 3d Perspective plugin (http://www.fcpeffects.com/collections/new-stuff/products/3d-perspective-plugin) to create this video: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=t6WkSERCRJU

I think it turned out great and the rest of the team love it too! Thanks for your help!